# Intimacy before marriage

Tags: marriage, sexuality

Many pastors in today Christian world have strict rules for intimacy before marriage. Although I'm not against it, I prefer strong biblical references for any Christian principle that Christians should follow.

Many people provide various verses such as 1 Corinthians 6:18, Ephesians 5:3, Hebrews 13:4 and etc. to support their argument. But any of them doesn't seem like addressing specifically the situation of before marriage.

Are there any biblical passages along with the cultural background, which can be interpreted to support the prohibition of premarital sex (i.e., sexual activities before marriage)?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please take the Tour which will assist you in understanding that questions which are really about a topic, rather than a single, specific text of scripture, are not, in essence, hermeneutical questions and may well be voted to hold for purely administrative reasons.

Comment: I believe his question is acceptable. Maybe it should be migrated to Christianity stack but if he has a better Biblical text it should stay

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between fornication and adultery. You can fornicate inside and outside of marriage, you can only commit adultery inside of marriage (put differently you can fornicate inside of marriage).

*taznûth and nâ'aph*

Adultery requires that you be married. You cannot commit adultery if you are not married because by definition you are breaking a wedlock

Fornication or whoredom/whoring does not require a marriage wedlock or covenant to be in place.

The dictionary defines fornication

> **voluntary sexual intercourse between two unmarried persons or two persons not married to each other.**

So your question is asking essentially, where does the Bible speak out against fornication?

Jesus speaks out against fornication

> “But I say unto you, That whosoever shall put away his wife, saving for the cause of **fornication**, causeth her to commit **adultery**: and whosoever shall marry her that is divorced committeth **adultery**.”
>   ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭5:32‬ ‭

Fornication is tightly linked to idolatry because in pagan temples there was a lot of fornication that took place as worship to idols. But the Bible speaks out against it, especially to gentile believers and juxtapositions it against idolatry, making it clear that it’s referring to sexual immorality not idol worship

> “But that we write unto them, that they abstain from pollutions of idols, and from **fornication**, and from things strangled, and from blood.”
>   ‭‭Acts‬ ‭15:20‬ ‭

There is a case described of fornication between two unmarried individuals in the NT

> “It is reported commonly that there is fornication among you, and such fornication as is not so much as named among the Gentiles, that one should have his father's wife.”
>   ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭5:1‬ ‭

There are also OT verses against fornication. So your question is a matter of definition. Similar to the situation when someone asks “is oral sex permissible in the Bible”.

The Bible doesn’t spell it out that way. It says rather

> “the sexually immoral, men who practice **homosexuality**, enslavers, liars, perjurers, and whatever else is contrary to sound doctrine,”
>   ‭‭1 Timothy‬ ‭1:10‬ ‭

What is homosexuality? It’s a subset of sodomy. You can be a heterosexual sodomite. How? Because of what sodomy is. Here is the definition of sodomy

> anal or oral copulation with a member of the opposite sex.

So the Bible does speak out against oral sex just not overtly because it speaks out against sodomy which includes oral sex (as well as anal sex both abhorrent to God).

*Sex before marriage or outside of marriage or outside of your own marriage is fornication and fornication is a sin and not acceptable in the Body of Christ.*

Comment: _So your question is asking essentially, where does the Bible speak out against fornication?_  As you explained fornication has various meanings. Actually my question is, **Does the Bible speak out against fornication, where fornication specially describes a situation of sexual activities between two unmarried persons.(unmarried to each other and any other person.)**

Comment: If you want to sin the Bible won’t stop you but know there are consequences.>> “Or do you not know that he who is joined to a prostitute becomes one body with her? For, as it is written, "The two will become one flesh."

Flee from fornication. Every other sin a person commits is outside the body, but the sexually immoral person (he that commits fornication) sins against his own body.”
‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭6:16, 18‬ ‭your comment tells me you don’t agree with definitions. Like you shall not murder, but where does it say “one person killing another person”. In the definition of the word, murder.

Comment: I'm not seeking permission to sin. As I mentioned even in the question, I'm not arguing against what you are saying. Thanks to you and the other answer I got valuable insight. I just wanted some more. Because cultural background can most probably be differ than today. (love affairs, dating, living together etc..) And usage of a word like fornication can also be differ. That's why I mentioned cultural background in the question. Anyway thank you very much for you valuable effort even though the question seems like off topic for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you on this:-

> How Is Porneia Used In the New Testament
>   1 Corinthians 7:2 makes it clear that porneia refers to sexual intercourse and sexual activity.
>
> But because of immoralities, each man should have relations with his own wife and each woman with her own husband.  1 Corinthians 7:2 (NASB)
>
> The word “immoralities” in this verse is translated from porneia. This helps us understand that porneia refers to **some form of sexual activity, including sexual intercourse.**
>
> Meaning of the Greek Word Porneia
>
> Conclusion:
>   The Greek word porneia includes all illicit sexual intercourse or sexual activity. The word can refer to prostitution, extramarital sexual intercourse, paedophilia, promiscuity, homosexuality, lesbianism, incest, premarital sex and bestiality.

From https://www.neverthirsty.org/bible-qa/qa-archives/question/what-is-meaning-of-greek-word-porneia-in-bible/